# Keyboard issues on HP Probook 650 G1: Lights up but not working

Tags: windows, operating-system, keyboard

I am currently experiencing an issue with my **HP Probook 650 G1 laptop keyboard**. Despite my attempts to install drivers and troubleshoot the issue, my keyboard still doesn't work. Interestingly, when I press the CAP or VER NUM keys on my external keyboard, the corresponding keys on my laptop keyboard light up, indicating that electric current is still passing through the keyboard. I am unsure what is causing this problem and would greatly appreciate any advice on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

Here's the screen
[my laptop keyboard light up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4yWi.jpg)

I have tried updating the system and keyboard drivers, as well as running the troubleshooting tool in Windows. However, these attempts have not resolved the issue. I was expecting that by updating the drivers and troubleshooting the problem, my laptop keyboard would start working normally again. Unfortunately, the problem persists, and I am unsure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware issue. Your keyboard has a life cycle usually 2 million key strokes. What could be the issue is keyboard itself. Wiring to the key or the risers could be faulty and not making proper contact to the specific key. I would recommend replacing the keyboard if other keys are not working.

The keys are designed to take a typing beating but they are not invincible. The keyboard depending on the style has a hinged cross bar like an X. When you look at the other side there is a little extension that goes between the gaps in the X that touches the surface. In turn it shots a signal to the software to execute that key function. After time and thousands of times hitting that surface it puts a small dent.

I suspect that the key is worn out and is not making proper contact. Common in all keyboards if your like me and are hard on them typing, playing games, etc.,..

Another thing is liquid spills. Anything sticky can cause poor connection between the keys and the part that shoots the signal.